# presentModalViewController: Differences

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

What is the difference between:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

and

```
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Where self is a subclass of UIViewController.

Along with that, does it matter how I dismiss the modal view?
Example:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If a modalView is presented by `self.navigationController`, will it be dismissed if called on `self`, and vice versa?

I know that apple recommends using a protocol and delegate in actual implementation, but I am just trying to find out if the behavior "under the hood" is the same or not.

I have been looking around to try and find an answer to this but I haven't found anything yet, so if this is a duplicate I apologize before hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

what kind of class are you calling this from (ie what is `self`). if you are you calling it from a view controller then the difference is that your view controller is presenting the `modalviewcontroller` instead of the view controller's `navigationcontroller` presenting the modal view

if you use `self.navigationcontroller` you can interact with `self.navigationitem` which a view controller doesn't have.

EDIT:

Yes, it gives you the ability to push additional `ViewControllers` onto the `self.navigationController.ViewControllers` array and then use the `navigationBar` to move from ViewController to ViewController.

As an example you could do `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];` and then if a user clicks a button you could push a ViewController `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`  Then a new View Controller/View would be presented inside of the ModalView. When you dismissed the ModalViewController you would still be transported back to your original view controller.

To answer your second question: You should dismiss the modal view the same way you presented it. So if you use self.navigationController to present, use self.navigationController to dismiss.

Comment: So does interacting with self.navigationItem give me something that presenting it without that does not?